# MongoDB (+ Node/Mongoose): How to track processed records without "marking" all of them?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have several large "raw" collections of documents which are processed in a queue, and the processed results are all placed into a single collection.

The queue only runs when the system isn't otherwise indisposed, and new data is being added into the "raw" collections all the time.

What I need to do is make sure the queue knows which documents it has already processed, so it doesn't either (a) process any documents more than once, or (b) skip documents. Updating each raw record with a "processed" flag as I go isn't a good option because it adds too much overhead.

I'm using MongoDB 4.x, with NodeJS and Mongoose. (I don't need a strictly mongoose-powered answer, but one would be OK).

My initial attempt was to do this by retrieving the raw documents sorted by `_id` in a smallish batch (say 100), then grabbing the first and last `_id` values in the return result, and storing those values, so when I'm ready to process the next batch, I can limit my `find({})` query to records with an `_id` greater than what I stored as the last-processed result.

But looking into it a bit more, unless I'm misunderstanding something, it appears I can't really count on a strict ordering by `_id`.

I've looked into ways to implement an auto-incrementing numeric ID field (SQL style), which *would* have a strict ordering, but the solutions I've seen look like they add a nontrivial amount of overhead each time I create a record (not dissimilar to what it would take to mark processed records, just would be on the insertion end instead of the processing end), and this system needs to process a LOT of records very fast.

Any ideas? Is there a way to do an auto-incrementing numeric ID that's super efficient? Will default `_id` properties actually work in this case and I'm misunderstanding? Is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid):

> While ObjectId values should increase over time, they are not
>   necessarily monotonic. This is because they:
>
> - Only contain one second of temporal resolution, so ObjectId values created within the same second do not have a guaranteed ordering, and
> - Are generated by clients, which may have differing system clocks.

So if you  are creating that many records per second then _id ordering is not for you.

However [Timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html#timestamps) within a mongo instance is **guaranteed to be unique**.

> BSON has a special timestamp type for internal MongoDB use and is not
>   associated with the regular Date type. Timestamp values are a 64 bit
>   value where:
>
> the first 32 bits are a time_t value (seconds since the Unix epoch)
>   the second 32 bits are an incrementing ordinal for operations within a
>   given second.
>
> **Within a single mongod instance, timestamp values are always unique.**

Although it clearly states that this is for `internal use` it maybe something for you to consider. Assuming you are dealing with a single mongod instance you can decorate your records when they are getting into the "raw" collections with timestamps ... then you could remember the last processed record only. Your queue would only pick records with timestamps larger that the last processed timestamp.

Comment: Have been testing with this method, and so far it seems to work perfectly.